# Regex: matching open/close tags which accepts another open/close tag with same name

Tags: php, regex, tags

Regex fans, hi.
In the code below, there are two parent tags (T1-4 and T5-6), and one child tag (T2-3).

How do you match T1-4 ?
or in general, how do you match the parent tags ?

```
<?php
$subject = '

{{poo}}             # T1
    Hello

    {{poo}}         # T2
        Nested 1
    {{/poo}}        # T3

{{/poo}}            # T4


{{poo}}             # T5
    Bye
{{/poo}}            # T6



';

$p = '!{{(\w+)}}(.*){{/\1}}!s';     // matches T1-6, too greedy
$p = '!{{(\w+)}}(.*?){{/\1}}!s';    // matches T1-3, not what I want

$p = '`(?xs) # xtended

{{(\w+)}}

.*?
(?R)?       # currently working on this one...

{{/\1}}


`';



preg_replace_callback($p, function($match){
    var_dump($match);
}, $subject);
```

Comment: Which ones are the parent tags? What's the expected output in this case?

Comment: @Amal Murali: parent tags are T1-4, T5-6, the expected output is the content of the tags. It should include also the tags itself.

Comment: Note that regular expressions are not the right tool for matching recursive structures since you can only parse regular languages with regular expressions. See here for an explanation: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html

Comment: @RolandKrüger Some regex engines like PCRE supports recursion (though they aren't really "regular expressions" any more).

Comment: @RolandKrüger: that's an interesting alternative indeed: to use html itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably what you are looking for:

```
$p = '`(?x)
{{(\w+)}}
# ( # you need probably this capture group later
(?>
    [^{]++
  |
    { (?!{)
  |
    {{ (?! /? \1 \b) # if needed you can add }} in the lookahead
  |
    (?R)
)*
# )
{{/\1}}
`';
```

Comment: That's an amazing regex, I love it

Comment: @ling: if you search on SO, you will see that it is a very classical/well know pattern type.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different answer:

```
~                       # Delimiter
{{(.*?)}}               # Match opening tag and put the name in group 1
(?:                     # Non-capturing group
   (?:(?!{{/?\1}}).)++  # Match anything that's not an opening/closing tag one or more times, no backtracking
   |                    # Or
   (?0)                 # Recurse the whole pattern, same as (?R)
)*                      # Repeat zero or more times
{{/\1}}                 # Match closing tag
~xs
```

I added the following modifiers:

- `x` : free-spacing mode, it's also there to have fancy comments in our regex.
- `s` : to match newlines with the dot.

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/rY4oM6)</kbd>

Comment: thanks, it works. Now that it's written down I can understand how it works. I chose Casimir et Hippolyte's answer though because I did a quick benchmark (a for loop with 10000 iterations) and it turns out that his (her?) solution is 10 times faster.

Comment: Upvoting both answers. Wondering if the speed difference is mostly because of Casimir's atomic `(?>`, or because of the "slow match" with lookahead at each step... but too lazy to test it. Probably the atomic, no? :)

Comment: @zx81 I think it's both plus the fact that s?he optimized it a little further with `[^{]++` and `{ (?!{)`